# How can I get the correct Lithuanian Keyboard layout?

Tags: 13.04, keyboard, xubuntu, keyboard-layout

I'm running Xubuntu 13.04 and I can't seem to get the right Lithuanian keyboard layout. None of layouts listed below works correct

[image]

Correct Lithuanian layout that I need:

[image]

Lithuanian symbols positioned in the place of digits: 1 for Ą, 2 for Č, 3 for Ę, 4 for Ė, 5 for Į, 6 for Š, 7 for Ų, 8 for Ū and = for Ž.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

To get the correct Lithuanian language support. Just need to select the Lithuanian language. Such as:

[image]

then everything works fine. Tested on Xubuntu 15.04. And selecting the Lithuanian (US keyboard with Lithuanian characters). Get better with the team `setxkbmap -variant`, but before the first reboot. That would be as follows:

[image]

then press Ok and everything works as it should work.

Comment: yep, selection of whole category "Lithuanian" instead of specific ones gives normal LT layout

Answer (score 1):

This is how I managed to get proper Lithuanian keyboard layout.

1. Choose "*Lithuanian (standard)*" from Keyboard layout selection window.
2. Set layout change option to "*Alt+Shift*" or anything else you like.
3. Change variant of the keyboard layout by executing command in terminal: `setxkbmap -variant ,`

Comment: If you want to load the script automatically in XFCE, then create a new entry via "_Settings Manager_" → "_Session and Startup_" → "_Application Autostart_" with the following command: `/bin/bash -c "sleep 5; setxkbmap -variant ,"`

Answer (score 0):

i took screenshots of these layouts from default ubuntu. take one then search for extended/special characters and compose key...
default:
[image: default]
ibm:
[image: ibmlst]
standard:
[image: standard]
us:
[image: us]

Comment: Thanks for your help pvtmert, if I understood correctly I need to adjust /etc/default/keyboard XKBOPTIONS="" with AltGr.. it seems to be easier install ubuntu default :)

Comment: Well, not necessarily. The AltGr key will only do want you want if you have the right layout. Ubuntu Unity has 6 keyboards listed: the 5 in your image plus 1 more - the one that you want. The question is why isn't the 6th keyboard listed.

Answer (score 0):

This may be only a partial answer.

Unity has the keyboard that you want. *Keyboard Layout* has all of the ones listed in your screenshot, but it also has one just called Lithuanian, which has the layout you are looking for.

It's located at `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/sun_vndr/lt` It's installed as part of the package `xkb-data` and is part of the [Xubuntu desktop](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/xubuntu-desktop).

The layout by itself is also available online: [xkeyboard-config-emacs](https://github.com/yuyichao/xkeyboard-config-emacs/blob/master/symbols/sun_vndr/lt)

You may be able to reinstall the package `sudo apt-get install --reinstall xkb-data`.

I *think* you can also copy the layout the same location if it's missing from your system; but I'm not entirely sure how XFCE/Xubuntu may have changed this configuration and whether or not you need to use any X11 command line tools.